# How to make a neural network output a specific number out of a certain range?

Tags: neural-network, regression, deep-learning

I have a neural network with an Input layer, 2 hidden Dense layers and an Output layer.

I would like for each neuron in the Output layer to give me a number between 0 and 2 (either 0, 1 or 2), like so:

[image: NN]

If I use a neuron for each possibility (a neuron for 0, a neuron for 1 and another for 2) and then pick the one with the best prediction, the output layer length would be far too much.

Is there a way to implement this ? (I am fairly new to neural networks and the like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

1. Scale your output data from [0, 2] to [0, 1] and apply Sigmoid activation at the end.
2. Make your own custom activation function that output everything in [0, 2]

I strongly suggest you no. 1, it's way faster to implement.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :) Could you kindly provide me with an example implementation (tutorial or the like) of such approach (approach number 1 or 2 or both)

Comment: I think you don't need a whole tutorial, just apply a basic Min-Max scaler on your Y data to implement method 1. If your Y data already is in [0, 2] then just do: `y = y/2` to get it in [0,1]. Alternatively, lots of people use `sklearn`'s `MinMaxScaler`.

Comment: Alrighty then, thank you so much :)

Comment: NP, remember to scale the data back one you're done training! :)

Comment: But doesn't this look like a classification problem ? The suggested solution seems to convert it into a regression.

Comment: For a neural network having 2+ hidden layers and only one activation function f(x) =x, will it improve the training error if we add more layers ?

Comment: That's impossible to say beforehand. Every dataset is different, every set of hyperparams is different. There's just so many variables involved. The only way is to try and check results. Adding hidden layers could either improve, or generate overfitting